# Filter next dropdown values based on already selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown with four options. I select the first option as 'John (1)' and add a row. Now the next dropdown should only show me three options in the dropdown ie, it should exclude the value of the previous dropdown selected value which is 'John (1)'. On the next add row it should exclude the previous two selected dropdown values. Can this be achieved. Thank you in advance. Below is the fiddle.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="mapping in viewTemplateRow">
            <td>
                <select class="form-dropdown" id="templateId" ng-model="mapping.id">
                    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="option in viewTemplateData" value="{{option.id}}" ng-selected="{{option.id == mapping.id}}" ng-model="viewTemplateData">{{option.name}} ( {{option.id}} )</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="button button-compact" ng-click="addRow();">Add New Row</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3787/

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to your ng-repeat in order to avoid allready added objects:

```
$scope.notSelected = function(item){
        for (var i in $scope.viewTemplateRow){
            if ($scope.viewTemplateRow[i].id==item.id)
            return false
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Your html will look like this:

```
<option ng-repeat="option in viewTemplateData | filter: notSelected" value="{{option.id}}" ng-selected="{{option.id == mapping.id}}" ng-model="viewTemplateData">{{option.name}} ( {{option.id}} )</option>
```

Note: Consider replace ng-repeat directive  for ng-options for a selector item.

Comment: The problem I see is that it modifies all the dropdowns because of the two way data binding. I want to make each dropdown with unique set of option values. For example first dropdown should have options as '1', '2', '3', '4'. Then if '1' is selected then on add row second dropdown should give me '2', '3', '4' as options keeping the first dropdown options still '1', '2', '3', '4' still intact.

Comment: you could use angular.copy() to copy objects and lose that reference of the two-way data binding.

Comment: tried using angular.copy(), not getting the desired output as mentioned above.

Comment: What about create a first selector with all options outside the ng-repeat without a filter. Then do what you want fr the rest of the selector. check this: https://jsfiddle.net/qwo099uy/1/